# Media player with slow motion, frame by frame, zoom, pan and scan, loop back

Tags: media-player

I need media player for windows with slow motion, frame by frame, zoom, [pan and scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_and_scan) and loop back. Also this player has to be launched from browser(i.e. i write local path of the video to browser, and browser starts playing it with the interface and functionality of the player). If there is web player with this capabilities it's also fine.

I checked multiple players, best one was VLC, but the problem with VLC is that their zoom option is in sub menu, and it's too complicated for our users to reach there.

Comment: What operating system? Please describe "pan and scan" in more detail: should it work on a frame or when playing too?

Comment: Windows, if it's not web player. I will be able to provide these details tomorrow, but i guess when playing too.

Comment: I just learnt more about pan and scan, and added a link. Do you also want the ability to play the movie while zoomed?

Comment: Yes. It's not for the movies, it will be a player to analyse sport videos. It's ok if player is not freeware.